# Bind data to a repeater in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a problem of binding data to a repeater control in runtime, I know how to bind data in aspx but cannot figure out how to do that in runtime. I have unknown number of rows to bind and in each row I have unknown number of items, this structure is a list of lists I've assigned it to the repeater data source in code behind. But to get the format I want What should I write instead of this code in ItemDataBound event in code behind?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterCategories" runat="server" OnItemCreated="RepeaterCategories_ItemCreated" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="parent1Link" runat="server" ForeColor="#570000" CommandArgument='<% #Eval("ParentID1") %>'
Text='<% #Eval("ParentName1") %>' Font-Size="Small" Font-Underline="False" Font-Bold="True"
Font-Names="Arial" PostBackUrl='<% #CategoryId(Eval("ParentID1")) %>'>
 </asp:LinkButton>
&nbsp;
 <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Width="7px" ImageUrl="~/Img/next.png" />
&nbsp;
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you should do:

Your aspx page

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_ItemDataBound">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li>
                                        <img id="imgArticle" runat="server"><p>
                                            <a href="#" id="aTitle" runat="server"></a>
                                        </p>
                                        <span class="grey">
                                            <asp:Literal ID="litCountry" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            <asp:Literal ID="litTime" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                        </span></li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

To bind the repeater:

```
rpt.DataSource = articles; // articles is a Generic List which has data
rpt.DataBind();
```

on Item databound:

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var item = (Article)e.Item.DataItem;
                if (item.Title != null)
                    ((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("aTitle")).InnerText = item.Title;
                if (item.Country != null)
                {
                    if (item.Country.Length > 0)
                        ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litCountry")).Text = item.Country + " ,";
                }
                ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litTime")).Text = item.CreationDate.ToString();

            }
        }
```

Comment: re: item.Country. There is a String function that would be better to use: `String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Country)` (3.5) or `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(item.Country)` (4.0). Otherwise, good answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you have a particularly complicated arrangement you have several choices. You could use a GridView with AutoGenerated columns and use OnItemDataBound to fine tunes things. Or you could of course just output raw HTML into a DIV.